# How to create a sms server using smslib

Tags: java, windows, sms-gateway, smslib

Guys I am currently looking at the SMSlib to send and receive SMS via a GSM modem. I was able to successfully receive and send the SMS through it. But what I need to do is to continually listen to SMS and respond to them accordingly. So i guess i need to build a SMS server. 
But I cannot figure out how to use the SMSServer of SMSlib. I read the documentation that came with the SMSlib but it was no help.(It uses ANT and other stuff on which I have no idea) 
Guys any help !!!! with a little elaborate answer......
Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Read documentation and download sample code from the below link .

http://smslib.org/

http://code.google.com/p/smslib/downloads/list

Comment: I already was able to send and receive the sms using smslib. The problem is with smsserver. I copied the smsserver.java to my project in eclipse but it show import errors. I guess it has something to do with the ANT stuff of which I have no idea about .